# Understanding a python code for a max flow problem

Tags: python, algorithm, graph-theory

I am trying to study a google foobar problem in [this](https://surajshetiya.github.io/Google-foobar/) blog post. (The problem is stated below.)

The author posts his code in the blog and claims that it is solved by [Dinic's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dinic%27s_algorithm#Algorithm).

I read Dinic's algorithm on the relevant Wikipedia page and watched a YouTube [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M6cm8UeeziI&ab_channel=WilliamFiset). I find that the code (attached below) is badly documented and I do not find a clue how the algorithm is implemented in the code. In particular, I do not see where the "level graph" and the "blocking flow" are constructed.

Could anyone see what the big while loop is doing in the function `bfs()`?

---

Given the starting room numbers of the groups of bunnies, the room numbers of the escape pods, and how many bunnies can fit through at a time in each direction of every corridor in between, figure out how many bunnies can safely make it to the escape pods at a time at peak.

Write a function answer(entrances, exits, path) that takes an array of integers denoting where the groups of gathered bunnies are, an array of integers denoting where the escape pods are located, and an array of an array of integers of the corridors, returning the total number of bunnies that can get through at each time step as an int. The entrances and exits are disjoint and thus will never overlap. The path element path[A][B] = C describes that the corridor going from A to B can fit C bunnies at each time step.  There are at most 50 rooms connected by the corridors and at most 2000000 bunnies that will fit at a time.

For example, if you have:

```
entrances = [0, 1] 
exits = [4, 5] 
path = [   [0, 0, 4, 6, 0, 0],  # Room 0: Bunnies   
           [0, 0, 5, 2, 0, 0],  # Room 1: Bunnies   
           [0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 4],  # Room 2: Intermediate room   
           [0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 6],  # Room 3: Intermediate room   
           [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],  # Room 4: Escape pods   
           [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],  # Room 5: Escape pods ]
```

Then in each time step, the following might happen:

```
0 sends 4/4 bunnies to 2 and 6/6 bunnies to 3 
1 sends 4/5 bunnies to 2 and 2/2 bunnies to 3 
2 sends 4/4 bunnies to 4 and 4/4 bunnies to 5 
3 sends 4/6 bunnies to 4 and 4/6 bunnies to 5
```

So, in total, 16 bunnies could make it to the escape pods at 4 and 5 at each time step.  (Note that in this example, room 3 could have sent any variation of 8 bunnies to 4 and 5, such as 2/6 and 6/6, but the final answer remains the same.)

```
def bfs(matrix, source, destination):
    visited = [-1 for i in range(len(matrix))]
    visited[source] = source
    queue = [source]
    while len(queue) > 0:
        top = queue.pop(0)
        for i in range(len(matrix)):
            if (matrix[top][i][1] - matrix[top][i][0]) != 0 and visited[i] == -1:
                if i == destination:
                    # Get route
                    visited[destination] = top
                    path = [destination]
                    temp = destination
                    while temp != source:
                        temp = visited[temp]
                        path.append(temp)
                    path.reverse()
                    # Get flow value and update augmented graph
                    temp = 1
                    total = float("inf")
                    cur = source
                    while temp != len(path):
                        entry = matrix[cur][path[temp]]
                        diff = abs(entry[1]) - entry[0]
                        total = min(total, diff)
                        cur = path[temp]
                        temp += 1
                    temp = 1
                    cur = source
                    while temp != len(path):
                        entry = matrix[cur][path[temp]]
                        if entry[1] < 0: # Already augmented need to flip
                            entry[1] += total
                        else:
                            entry[0] += total
                        entry = matrix[path[temp]][cur]
                        if entry[1] <= 0: # Already augmented need to flip
                            entry[1] -= total
                        else:
                            entry[0] += total
                        cur = path[temp]
                        temp += 1
                    return True
                else:
                    visited[i] = top
                    queue.append(i)
    return False

def answer(entrances, exits, path):
    max_val = sum(list(map(sum, path)))
    aug = []
    for i in range(len(path)):
        aug.append([])
        for j in range(len(path[i])):
            aug[i].append([0, path[i][j]])
        aug[i].append([0, 0])
        if i in exits:
            aug[i].append([0, max_val])
        else:
            aug[i].append([0, 0])
    aug.append([])
    aug.append([])
    for i in range(len(path[0]) + 2):
        if i in entrances:
            aug[-2].append([0, max_val])
        else:
            aug[-2].append([0, 0])
        aug[-1].append([0, 0])
    while bfs(aug, len(aug)-2, len(aug)-1):
        pass
    total = 0
    for i in range(len(aug)):
        total += aug[-2][i][0]
    return total
```

Comment: the algorithm implemented in the code looks more like Ford-Fulkerson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The author is mistaken. This code implements [Edmonds–Karp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edmonds%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm) (which specializes Ford–Fulkerson, so turtle's comment is correct), which repeatedly augments a shortest path in the residual network.

Comment: Thank you very much, David! No wonder it does not like Dinic's algorithm at all. I did not know Edmonds-Karp.